# Normal distribution, absolute values

Tags: probability

Let X be normally distributed with $E(X)=3$, and $Var(X)=4$, calculate $P(|X-3|<K)=0.76$.

I hope I did calculate it correctly? I would be glad if anyone could point out any mistakes... here is how I did it:

$$ P(|X-3|  < K)=0.76= \\$$
$$P(-(X-3) < K \land X-3 < K)= \\$$
$$ P(X-3 > -K \land X-3 < K)\\$$
$$ P(-K/2<Z<K/2)\\$$
$$ \Phi(K/2)-\Phi(-K/2)=0.76\\$$
$$2 \Phi(K/2)=0.76$$

$$ K=2.35 $$

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\Phi(-y)=1-\Phi(y)$ you should actually get $2\Phi(K/2)=1.76$, but you otherwise have the right strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Your work up to $\Phi(K/2) - \Phi(-K/2) = 0.76$ is good.

However, you made a mistake afterward, as $-\Phi(-K/2) \ne \Phi(K/2)$. You may be thinking of $\Phi(-K/2) = 1 - \Phi(K/2)$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I get it know!